# How to describe ceiling- and floor-like functions that round to a specific decimal place?

Tags: notation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to describe floors and ceilings with non-integer factors.
Rather than rounding up or down to the nearest integer, I need to for example round to the nearest 0.1.

For example, in what I'm writing, $\lfloor3.21\rfloor$ should give $3.2$

How can I represent that?

- $\lfloor3.21\rfloor^{0.1}$ ?
- $\lfloor3.21\rfloor_{0.1}$ ?

I could just guess and use a superscript or subscript, as shown above but I wanted to know if there's a more formal way of representing such non-integer floors/ceilings and I have not been able to find any.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about $\lfloor 10x\rfloor/10$?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I was hoping to have something a little closer to how one would describe it linguistically "round down to the nearest tenth" kind of thing. (If it exists!)

Comment: What do you mean?  You just described it.  "Round to the nearest $0.1$".  What more needs to be said?

Comment: Sorry @fleablood, my need is not simply to communicate a single value, my actual use case is a little more involved. My question boils down to "Is there a formal way of representing non-integer floors/ceilings" - "No" is a perfectly valid answer to the question (though J. W. Tanner's workaround is very helpful)

Comment: You can say:  "for any real number $x$ there is unique integer $n$ so that $\frac n{10} \le x < \frac {n+1}{10}$.  We will refer to the value $\frac n{10}$ as the *the  floory tenthmabob* of $x$.  And we will write is as $\#\@[^x]\@\#$".   Then every time you need to refer to it you can say "the floory tenthmabob" and write it as $\#\@[^x]\@\#$.  Example:  The floory tenghmabob of $\pi$ is $3.1$ and $\#\@[^\pi]\@\# = 3.1$.  There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: J.W. Tanner's comment hints as to why it's not considered necessary to have terminology or notation.  If $\frac nk \le x < \frac {n+1}k$ then $n \le kx < n+1$ and $n=\lfloor kx\rfloor$ and $\frac nk = \frac {\lfloor kx\rfloor}k$.

Comment: Thank you, this both answers the question (no there's not), and provides and explains the workaround. While I'd still love a more succinct way of representing it for my specific use case, this more than answers the question itself if you'd like to submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are of course free to devise your own notation, provided you define it before you use it.  However, your notation should be designed to avoid confusion or ambiguity when used with other established notations; e.g., a superscript would be confused with exponentiation, as well as become unwieldy if you actually wanted to use both operations; e.g., what does $$(\lfloor 3.21 \rfloor^{0.1})^2$$ mean?  But there is no "standard" or canonical notation for what you propose.  The way we would mathematically write such an operation is to do what was proposed in one of the comments:  for some base $b$, the expression $$\frac{\lfloor b^m n \rfloor}{b^m}$$ represents the greatest number less than or equal to $n$ to within $m$ digits of base-$b$ precision; e.g. for $b = 10$ and $m = 1$, this is the greatest tenth of an integer less than or equal to $n$.  For $b = 2$ and $m = 3$, this is the greatest binary number to within $3$ bits precision less than or equal to $n$, so if $n = (11.3257)_{10}$, that is to say, we wrote this in base $10$, $$\frac{\lfloor 8n \rfloor}{8} = (11.25)_{10} = (1011.010)_{2}.$$